# If I share a link with edit access to a Google Doc or Spreadsheet, but not make someone a collaborator, will they be notified about comments?

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs-api

I do a lot of collaboration externally for work, but want to know ways around clients not seeing how we edit and work. Would the above be a way to get around clients being notified of comments? Is there any way to make sure nobody gets notified about comments?